# why is the output of these two codes different?

Tags: python-3.x, string

## first code

```
s = input ('enter a word:')
s = s[:4] + 'X' + s[5:]
print (s)
```

output:

```
enter a word: python
pytXon
```

## other code

```
s = 'python'
s = s[:4] + 'X' + s[5:]
print (s)
```

output:

```
pythXn
```

Comment: Cannot replicate your issue.

Comment: You are entering word after one space because of that. **enter a word: python**. So avoid space or make **s.strip()**

Answer (score 2):

Given your prompt (without trailing space) and how you display what appeared in your console, you almost certainly entered a leading space to make it look nice. If you output

```
print(repr(s))
```

you will notice that the first one actually generates

```
" pytXon"
```

You can add a space or line break to your prompt:

```
s = input('enter a word: ')  # OR
s = input('enter a word:\n')
```

and/or sanitize the input:

```
s = s.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this.

```
s = (input ('enter a word: ')).strip()
s = s[:4] + 'X' + s[5:]
print (s)


s = 'python'
s = s[:4] + 'X' + s[5:]
print (s)
```